# Deleting Value From Multi Dimensional Map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, voxel

I am currently making my own voxel engine in c++, however I seem to have come across a problem.

I am using a chunk based system and storing it in a 3-dimensional map, the variable definition looks like this:

```
map<uint64_t,map<uint64_t,map<uint64_t,Chunk*>>> Chunks;
```

However, I can't really find a proper way to delete any value from the map, I have tried using the `map::erase` function but with no succes, is there any good way to do this that I am unaware of?

P:S
This was the `map::erase` function I was trying:

```
Chunks[x][y].erase(z);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did that erase function throw an error, or did it simply not erase what you wanted?

Comment: Define "proper way".

Comment: Could you show how you tryng to delete? An input example also?

Comment: Note, as an aside, that you may be leaking a Chunk object since you use raw pointers.

Comment: code11; it simply didn't throw any error.

Comment: what I mean with "proper way" is that I simply want it to erase the value completly, get rid of the memory allocation (as that is my issue to begin with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map is a key-value type, so you cannot try access as array:

Try to remove the first element by example:

```
Chunks.erase(KeyOfFirstElement);
```

from: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/

Comment: Wouldn't that erase not a value, but a entire row?

Comment: Yes, for sure it will delete the actual layer and your children.. If you want the lower layer you will need to access the elements inside your map, extracting the first layer, second, until you reach the map you want and then remove an element...

Comment: Why are you using it, this way 3d-map? probably there is a better approach using another data-structure, if you put into your question the Input information and the Output you want probably we can help you ;)

Comment: Oh I'm sure this isn't the best way to do it, but it was the only real way I could figure out. Plus; It's extremly fast.

Comment: That is my point, put the INPUT you have and the Outputs you want and surely we'll help ;)

Comment: So, after a little while I figured it out. Thanks for all the help.